# Калькулятор с вводом выражения в одну строку и умеющий работать с римскими и арабскими цифрами. Как обработать исключения?

Tags: java

Прошу помочь. Правильно ли я применил try-catch для чисел вне диапазона `[1...10]`? Как обработать исключения:

1. ввод не целых чисел(калькулятор принимает только целые),
2. работает либо с арабскими, либо с римскими
3. неправильная арифметическая операция (правильные `a + b`, `a - b`, `a * b`, `a / b`)  ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class calc {
    private static int value(char r) {...}

    private static int romanToDecimal(String str) {....}

    private static String intToRoman(int num) {....}

    private static int calculate(int number1, int number2, char operation){...}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer[] arabic = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
        String[] roman = {"X", "IX", "VIII", "VII", "VI", "V", "IV", "III", "II", "I"};
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] blocks = text.split(" ");
        int number1 = 0, number2 = 0;
        String operation = " ";
        operation = blocks[1];
        char operation2 = operation.charAt(0);
        boolean flag = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < roman.length; i++) {
            if (roman[i].equals(blocks[0]) || roman[i].equals(blocks[2])) {
                flag = true;
            }
        }    
        try {
            if (flag) {
                number1 = romanToDecimal(blocks[0]);
                number2 = romanToDecimal(blocks[2]);
                System.out.println(intToRoman(calculate(number1, number2, operation2)));

            } else {
                number1 = Integer.parseInt(blocks[0]);
                number2 = Integer.parseInt(blocks[2]);
                System.out.println(calculate(number1, number2, operation2));
            }
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            if ((number1 > 10 || number1 < 1) || (number2 > 10 || number2 < 1)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я что-то не понял маневра с flag. Если хотя бы один элемент - римская запись, то мы берем за истину, что оба элемента - римские записи.

Comment: здесь недаработка, хотя бы два элемента - римская запись

Comment: Необходимо ввести переменные isRoman1, isRoman2. Далее если оба истинны - производим парс, если одна истинна и одна ложна - то запись неверна, если обе ложны, то пробуем перевести обе в int(try, дальше пишем перевод). Зашли в catch - значит запись неверна.

Comment: у меня ничего не работает, я не понимаю, могу я с вами договориться? ваше время на показ как сделать нужно правильно в обмен на что-то

Comment: Что вы можете предложить? Сделать могу.

Comment: @ Miron, напишите мне пжл в телеграм @plaza2009

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101437/discussion-between-plaza2009-and-miron).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Если вы попытаетесь выполнить, например это - `Integer.parseInt("1.22")`, то вам выкинет `java.lang.NumberFormatException`. Оберните ваши парсы в соответствующий try catch
2. Создайте try catch для `Integer.parseInt`. Переводите в int оба элемента в блоке try. Если они оба не числовые, то зайдет в catch. Далее вы получаете либо два элемента в римской записи, либо два элемента, один из которых точно записан неправильно. Если вы пробежались по массиву констант, и обнаружили элемент, не входящий в этот массив, значит элемент записан неверно. Кидайте ошибку.
3. Если операция не равна ни одному из строчек константного массива `new String[]{"+", "-", "*", "/"}`, то данная арифметическая операция неправильна.

Comment: пойду разбирать, а для 3-го эта ошибка нужна IllegalArgumentException?

Comment: Нужна, ведь это нелегальный аргумент